# Stop the comma separation at the last result

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array stored in a variable called `$data` that looks like this:

```
["data"]=>
    ["rows"]=>
    array(30) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "2016-08-15"
        [1]=>
        int(3)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "2016-08-16"
        [1]=>
        int(18)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "2016-08-17"
        [1]=>
        int(5)
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "2016-08-18"
        [1]=>
        int(3)
      }
      [4]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "2016-08-19"
        [1]=>
        int(11)
      }
      [5]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "2016-08-20"
        [1]=>
        int(5)
      }
```

And I try to take the values from 30 entries and add a comma and a space:

```
                    <?php
                    foreach ($data->data->rows as $data) {
                        if (isset($data[1])) {
                            echo $data[1] . ', ';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

The result looks like this:

```
[18, 5, 3, 11, 5, 7, 9, 7, 17, 6, 3, 3, 1, 19, 13, 7, 3, 4, 10, 3, 5, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1, 8, 10, 6, 9, ],
```

But after the last entry I don't want to have a comma and the space. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I advise you this solution:

```
$values = [];
foreach ($data->data->rows as $data) {
    if (isset($data[1])) {
        $values[] = $data[1];
    }
}
echo implode(',', $values);
```

Also if you're trying to get json string - better use `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode($values);
```

Comment: Indeed using json_encode was a better way. Thank you for your time and for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Just use [implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php):

```
$prepared_array = array_column($data, 1);

$result = array_implode(', ',$prepared_array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. This solution works but in my case I should've also used json_encode. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure that got you properly but my code give you the same results. There is no problem to add ***json_encode*** in the end. My solution allow you to get rid of **foreach statement**

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes you can use it using implode as well as you own logic..
<?php
 foreach ($data->data->rows as $key => $data) {
  if (isset($data[1])) {
    echo $data[1];
    if($key === count($data->data->rows) -1){
      echo ' , ';
    }
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this low-tech solution:

```
<?php
    $sep = "";
    foreach ($data->data->rows as $data) {
        if (isset($data[1])) {
            echo $sep . $data[1];
            $sep = ', ';
        }
    }
?>
```

Basically what you are doing is setting the delimiter in front of the string.  It's empty at first, so there will be no delimiter, but after the first iteration it will be populated, putting the delimiter in front of all future strings.  Also, because it is in the beginning, there is nothing to trail after the last one.

Perhaps not the best solution, but certainly easy and understandable.